# Spring MVC 3.0.5.RELEASE get bean from the controller without scan

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-ioc

I have defined this bean:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service(value = "deviceService")
public class DeviceServiceImpl implements DeviceService {
...
}
```

and this config file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
   <bean name="/hello" class="com.tdk.DeviceController"></bean>
   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Is there a way to get the **deviceService** bean from the controller without scanning ?

Answer (score 0):

Without Component Scan deviceService will never be loaded in application context , and you can't inject a bean which dosen't even exist.

You already have a dispatcher-servlet.xml so you can use xml based approach to define deviceService bean.

```
<bean name="deviceService" class="com.*.DeviceServiceImpl"></bean>
```

and then use property injection for your controller

```
<bean name="/hello" class="com.tdk.DeviceController">
<property name="deviceService" ref="deviceService" />
</bean>
```

Hope , this will help.